# API Management Service : How to import Service Fabric Cluster APIs?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management, azure-sdk-.net

We have created two APIs and deployed them to a Service Fabric Cluster, which exposes them as https://[clusterurl]:8100 and https://[ClusterURL]>:8101.

Now we want to expose these APIs via API Management Service, and we couldn't find any easy way to do so. There is one article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-api-management, but it's really very hard to understand and relate it with this SDK.

We managed to create an API Management Service instance and also to create a blank API (or import through Swagger) using the SDK. But we don't know how to import the Service Fabric API.

And we could create an API Management BackEnd pointing to the Service Fabric app, but then we couldn't find any way to bind this BackEnd to any API created in the API Management Service.

Any help, sample, and/or pointing in right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For service fabric integration to work you need:

1. VNET that includes both your SF cluster and APIM instance.
2. Backend entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/backend/createorupdate it will let APIM know where your cluster is and provide it with necessary credentials to make calls.
3. set-backend-service policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService It's usually placed in inbound section of API that needs to talk to SF. You should omit "base-url" attribute, use "backend-id" to specify id of backend entity created in previous point, and other "sf-*" to configure how exactly call should be made.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now, I have created an API, I created a BackEnd and I also created a policy giving backend-id. So now, when I go to Azure portal and go to APIM-> API and click on this new API, it shows that fabric URL in the BackEnd. So far so good. But there are no operation. So , how do I test it ? Can this not import the operation just like an API when imported with OpenAPI or WSDL ?

Comment: If you have OpenAPI spec available you should import it first, and then add set-backend-service policy. Try importing from URL if spec is publicly available, otherwise import it as a file

Comment: Thanks once again. Understood. One more question: Is there any other way to get Operations in API Management Service if the underlying API is NOT having Swagger ? Any workaround ? I am trying to create tool for my organization where other developers can import their API under API Management service, so it is possible they don't have added Swagger while creating API.
Thanks once again.

Comment: Sure. That only means that you'll have to add operations manually through Azure Portal. Or if there is some sort of automation you can come up with, then you could use API or SDK to do that.